# Let negl1 and negl2 be negligible functions

Tags: encryption, public-key, keys, decryption, negligible

[image]

can we still consider the second function negligible ? is there any main differences between them?

Comment: what have you thought of? this is not a homework answering service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know the definition of [negligible function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligible_function) and some properties of the operation between $negl()$ and polynomial $p(n)$.
Also, you should confirm what $negl_4()$ and $negl_5()$ are, that is, you need more information about $negl_4()$ and $negl_5()$.

I got some help and reminders from @[kelalaka](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/18298/kelalaka), here thank you!

Comment: You cannot say anything about $negl_6$ since there is no information about $negl_4$ and $negl_5$ are negligible other than their name! In the first part, it is was mentioned that $negl_1$ and $negl_2$ are negligible. And, please refrain yourself from answering HW question as [our last policy](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1115/18298)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a new member trying to help others, and I've reflected on my behavior, and I think it's not doing well, so I'll revise my answer right away. If there are any other questions here, I would like you to point them out!